# How to calculate the standard error of ratio of two AUC

Tags: standard-error, auc, ratio

Please can anyone help me with this!

I hope my explanation is going to be simple:

This is the data I have:

[image]

I only have access to the aggregated data as below. the first column is the time points a measurement was taken, the second column is the treatment group, the third column is the number of subjects measured at each timepoint, fourth and fifth column is the mean and standard deviation of the measurement at each time point.

I want to calculate the area under the curve using trapezoid rule (using months in the x axis and y the measurements) for group 0 and group 1 and then the ratio of AUC1/AUC0.

The AUC for group 0 is 2252.449951172 and for group 1 is 2164.100097656, so the ratio is .96077611 which suggests that group 1 has a reduction of about 4% in the AUC compared with group 0

My problem is: how do I calculate the Standard Error for the ratio of two AUCs?

Please, could you show the calculation with example?

I will only have access to the info showed below: N, means and SD at each timepoint.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Andre